# Jquery ui-autocomplete has no value

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, combobox, return-value

I've been looking all over for a solution to this. I want to hide/show divs based on the selection within a jquery combobox. If I display the underlying select box and make the selection that way it works but I can't get it to work with my combobox.

You can see an example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/RDd3A/71/

If you select any option besides the first option the div should be hidden. If you make the underlying select box display #combobox and select this way it works.

How do I get this to work using the combobox only?

Comment: Before looking - I assume you've handled the select event in your autocomplete declaration? If you have, make sure you've told it to fire the change event for the dropdown if there is any code attached to that. Just initial suggestions...

Comment: Can you post the relevant HTML/Script please as this question will be useless to any future user with similar issue if all they see is a link to another web-site and the link either is dead or the issue no longer persists there. In **addition** to the relevant code a fiddle on jsFiddle.net is always handy too.

Comment: I updated my question to have a simple fiddle rather than the whole webpage. kpcrash I am not sure what you mean, could you take a look at my fiddle and see if I am doing what you are asking? Thanks

Comment: Check this one out - http://jsfiddle.net/kpcrash/3pgxt/ Overriding the combobox() function with a means to fire the original select's onchange event.

Comment: Thank you kpcrash! I've seen that code before but haven't been able to get it to work with my autocomplete until now. You're a lifesaver.